# flutter pass context to another class

Tags: flutter, localization, android-context

I am making an application on flatter. I made a class in which I created data for the ListView and which I pass to another class for display. How can i pass context to this class to do localization?

```
data_rules.dart
class DataRules {
  const DataRules({required this.name, required this.description, required this.image});
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String image;
}
class RulesList{
  final BuildContext context;
  RulesList({required this.context});
  final List<DataRules> rulesList= [
    DataRules(
      name: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('welcom')!,,
      description: '..',
      image: 'assets/images/rules1.png',
    ),
    DataRules(
     name: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('welcom')!,,
      description: '..',
      image: 'assets/images/rules2.png',
    ),
  ];
}

form.dart
class Rules extends State<RulesForm>  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<DataRules> _rulesList= RulesList(context: context).rulesList;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: _rulesList.length,
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `wiget.` in front.

```
  name: AppLocalizations.of(widget.context).translate('welcom')!,,
```